# Twilio - Invalid Content-Type (PHP)

Tags: php, twilio, mms, twilio-php

Here is my PHP code for sending the message:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$client->account->messages->sendMessage(
    "+15625551212",
    "+17145551212",
    "This is a test",
    "http://ovio.us/profile_images/5.png"
);
```

The Debug Console shows these Response Headers:
**Date** Fri, 18 Nov 2016 15:00:52 GMT
**Server** Apache/2.4.23
**Last-Modified** Fri, 18 Nov 2016 14:36:46 GMT
**ETag** "bc001d0-260f-541943c54c496"
**Accept-Ranges** bytes
**Content-Length** 9743
**Content-Type** image/png
**X-Cache** MISS from ip-172-18-20-243.ec2.internal
**X-Cache-Lookup** MISS from ip-172-18-20-243.ec2.internal:3128

As far as I know image/png is a valid content-type:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/accepted-mime-types

Comment: Hey, Twilio developer evangelist here. Would you be able to try with another image? Say: https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png for example?

Comment: That works. So is there something wrong with the image in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Marcos' comment, I determined that the saved image had the PNG extension, but wasn't really a PNG file.

Edit: So what I did was modified my PHP script to convert any uploaded images to PNG using imagepng().

Comment: Exactly! I was manually setting Content-Type i.e. image/jpeg and the file had extension .jpeg but the bits of the file had PNG at the start... so then Twilio gave the 12300 Invalid Content-Type error. So make sure to BOTH set Content-Type and make sure to convert the file.